# How to search for a particular data in the url using python

Tags: python

Hello i'm working in something and i have got stucked in a script whose first method takes a string argument and do a google search on it the it moves into in the second method which is takes the result of the website

for ex:

```
from googlesearch import search

class online():
      def __init__(self):
            self.search = ""
      def get_url(self):
           for i in search(self.search,num_resuls=10):
                     return i

      def dump_data(self):
            pass
```

so let's say that the search = how to make money?

it will give me the link to an article

so how can i dump that data which answer this question in the url?

and the search() method from googlesearch module only returns 1 url how can i fix that?

Comment: the return statement in get_url means the function will only return the first result

Comment: how to make it returns all possible values?

Comment: Try a `yield` rather than a return in `get_url()`, or append the values of `i` to a list and then return that list

Comment: it depends on what you want.  do you want get_url to return a list of all 10 search results?  do you want it to simply return the generator so you can iterate over it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to iterate over the top 10 search results, then you can simply return the generator that search() returns.  Something like this:

```
from googlesearch import search


class Google(object):
    def __init__(self, terms):
        self.terms = terms

    def get_urls(self):
        return search(self.terms, num_results=10)

    def dump_data(self):
        pass


for url in Google("how to make money?").get_urls():
    print(url)
```

Note it's a bad idea to name your class attributes the same name (e.g. "search") as the function you imported.